# Get project custom fields Project Online using Javascript

Tags: custom-field-types, project-online

I am currently working on Project Online 2013 and I am developing an app with use of Enterprise Custom Fields where I need to list all the custom fields that have project entity type alone (not task or resources).

I could get the list of all Custom Fields by `PS.ProjectContext.get_customFields()`. But could not filter it by project entity type.

Could anyone  please recommend how to write a Javascript(or REST/jQuery) method to retrieve the project custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve custom fields of a specific project you can use the below endpoint

```
<site url>/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('<<guid>>')/CustomFields
```